# django: UnboundLocalError local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to make a social web app with django. I made a form that a user can use to answer a question. Everything worked fine but when I submit form without any content (empty form), I got an error

`(Unbound Local error "local variable 'new_answer' referenced before assignment")`

I'm new to django and I don't know much about this so any help will be very kind.
here is my view code:

```
def question_detail(request, pk):
    question=get_object_or_404(Question, pk=pk)
    #list of active answers for this question
    answers = question.answers.filter(active=True)
    answer_form = AnswerForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        #a comment was posted
        answer_form = AnswerForm(data=request.POST or None)
        if answer_form.is_valid():
            new_answer= answer_form.save(commit=False)
            new_answer.question = question
            u=request.user
            new_answer.name = u
            new_answer.save()
    else:
        answer_form = AnswerForm()
        new_answer = False
    question_tags_ids = question.tags.values_list('id', flat=True)
    similar_questions = Question.objects.filter(tags__in = question_tags_ids)\
                    .exclude(id=question.id)
    similar_questions = similar_questions.annotate(same_tags=Count('tags'))\
                    .order_by('-same_tags','-created')[:4]
    return render(request,'dashboard/post/detail.html',
              {'question':question,
               'answer_form':answer_form,
               'new_answer': new_answer,
               'similar_questions':similar_questions})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the portion of code.

```
if request.method=='POST':
    #a comment was posted
    answer_form = AnswerForm(data=request.POST or None)
    if answer_form.is_valid():
        new_answer= answer_form.save(commit=False)
        new_answer.question = question
        u=request.user
        new_answer.name = u
        new_answer.save()
```

If the user submits the form and if the answer_form is invalid or empty, then you should write an else to display the errors, eg:

```
if request.method=='POST':
#a comment was posted
    answer_form = AnswerForm(data=request.POST or None)
    if answer_form.is_valid():
        new_answer= answer_form.save(commit=False)
        new_answer.question = question
        u=request.user
        new_answer.name = u
        new_answer.save()
    else:
        #code to handle invalid form submission
```

Comment: thanks I tried your suggestion and now it's working well.